# basic algebra: additive inverse simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

Sorry for my basic lack of algebra here. It's been a while. Is my simplification here correct?
$$x-(x+y)$$
Additive inverse:
$$x+(-x)+(-y)$$
A positive and negative becomes subtraction
$$x-x-y$$
x - x is always 0
$$0 - y$$
and finally remove the 0
$$-y$$

Comment: Yes, correct! Welcome to Math.SE, hope you stay and contribute to the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in \Bbb R, y\in \Bbb R$ and $z\in \Bbb R$.

By definition, $x-z=x+(-z)$

$x+y+(-y)+(-x)=x+0+(-x)=x+(-x)=0$

Then $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)$

So, $x-(x+y)=x+(-x)+(-y)$... (like you)

Welcome.